# Image browser in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

The code below displays thumbnails in a left pane. When a thumbnail is clicked, the full-size image appears in the right pane.

[image: image-browser]

I have the impression that even though this code is rather brief, it is not the most natural way to do this task in Qt. Am I reinventing the wheel? Are there Model-View classes that are more suitable for this task?

```
// main.cpp
#include "PixmapPair.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSplitter>
#include <QGridLayout>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QSplitter* page = new QSplitter;

    QGridLayout* gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
    QWidget* leftPane = new QWidget(page);
    leftPane->setLayout(gridLayout);
    QLabel* rightPane = new QLabel(page);
    PixmapPair pair1(":/images/ocean.jpg",  gridLayout, rightPane);
    PixmapPair pair2(":/images/forest.jpg", gridLayout, rightPane);

    page->setWindowTitle("Images");
    page->show();
    return app.exec();
}

// PixmapPair.h
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout>
class PixmapPair : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PixmapPair(QString file, QGridLayout * gridLayout, QLabel* rp)
        : rightPane(rp), largePixmap(file)
    {
        smallPixmap = largePixmap.scaled(QSize(100,100), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
        QPushButton* pushButton = new QPushButton;
        pushButton->setIcon(QIcon(smallPixmap));
        pushButton->setFlat(true);
        pushButton->setIconSize(QSize(100,100));
        QObject::connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(displayInRightPane()));
        gridLayout->addWidget(pushButton);
    }
public slots:
    void displayInRightPane()
    {
        rightPane->setPixmap(largePixmap);
    }
private:
    QLabel* rightPane;
    QPixmap largePixmap;
    QPixmap smallPixmap;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left part of the `SplitView` is basically a list presenting all the available pictures. Qt provides a way to handle this using the model/view pattern.

The class for showing a list is a `QListView`, it will do the job automatically based on a model given with the function `setModel()`.
This function requires a `QAbstractItemModel`, since this class is a pure abstract one we will need to create a custom class deriving from it.
Inheriting from it will require a lot of glue code but thankfully Qt already provides a class that takes care of most of it when we want to represent a list, it is called `QAbstractListModel`.

So I created an ImageListModel like this :

```
///////////////////////  
// imagelistmodel.h ///  
#ifndef IMAGELISTMODEL_H  
#define IMAGELISTMODEL_H  

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QPixmap>

struct PixmapPair
{
        QString _file;
        QPixmap _small;
        QPixmap _large;
};

class ImageListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        // QAbstractItemModel retrieves various information (like text, color, ...)
        // from the same index using roles. We can define custom ones, however to 
        // avoid a clash with predefined roles, ours must start at Qt::UserRole. 
        // All numbers below this one are reserved for Qt internals.
        enum Roles
        {
            LargePixmapRole = Qt::UserRole + 1
        };

        explicit ImageListModel(std::initializer_list<QString> files, QObject *parent = 0);
        virtual ~ImageListModel();

        // QAbstractItemModel interface ===========================
    public:
        int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
        QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
        // ========================================================

    private:
        QList<PixmapPair*> _data;
};

#endif // IMAGELISTMODEL_H

///////////////////////
// imagelistmodel.cpp /
#include "imagelistmodel.h"

ImageListModel::ImageListModel(std::initializer_list<QString> files, QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    auto iter = files.begin();

    while (iter != files.end())
    {
        QPixmap large(*iter);
        PixmapPair *pair = new PixmapPair();
        pair->_file = *iter;
        pair->_large = large;
        pair->_small = large.scaled(100, 100, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

        _data.append(pair);
        ++iter;
    }
}

ImageListModel::~ImageListModel()
{
    qDeleteAll(_data);
}


int ImageListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    // This function should return the number of rows contained in the parent  
    // parameter, the parent parameter is used for trees in order to retrieve the  
    // number of rows contained in each node. Since we are doing a list each element  
    // doesn't have child nodes so we return 0  
    // By convention an invalid parent means the topmost level of a tree. In our case  
    // we return the number of elements contained in our data store.
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0;
    else
        return _data.count();
}

QVariant ImageListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        switch (role)
        {
            case Qt::DecorationRole:
            {
                // DecorationRole = Icon show for a list
                return _data.value(index.row())->_small;
            }
            case Qt::DisplayRole:
            {
                // DisplayRole = Displayed text
                return _data.value(index.row())->_file;
            }
            case LargePixmapRole:
            {
                // This is a custom role, it will help us getting the pixmap more
                // easily later.
                return _data.value(index.row())->_large;
            }
        }
    }

    // returning a default constructed QVariant, will let Views knows we have nothing 
    // to do and we let the default behavior of the view do work for us.
    return QVariant();
}
///////////////////////
```

Our list is now ready and we are almost done.

```
// main.cpp ///////////
#include <QApplication>

#include <QSplitter>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QListView>

#include "imagelistmodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSplitter page;
    QListView *imageList = new QListView(&page);
    imageList->setModel(new ImageListModel({ "ocean.jpg", "forest.jpg" }, imageList));
    // We tell the list view to show our icon, this mode will call the data function
    // of our model with the role : DecorationRole.
    imageList->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
    // We want our list to show data vertically
    imageList->setFlow(QListView::TopToBottom);
    // We allow only one selection at a time in the list
    imageList->setSelectionMode(QListView::SingleSelection);
    QLabel *imagePresenter = new QLabel(&page);

    // We connect to the signal emitted when the selection is changed
    // to update the image presenter.
    QObject::connect(imageList->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged, [imageList, imagePresenter] {
        QModelIndex selectedIndex = imageList->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().first();
        // We use our custom role here to retrieve the large image using the selected
        // index.
        imagePresenter->setPixmap(selectedIndex.data(ImageListModel::LargePixmapRole).value<QPixmap>());
    });

    page.setWindowTitle("Images");
    page.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Advantages for this solution are:
- We can easily add filtering by wrapping our custom ListModel into a QSortFilterProxyModel.
- No need to create and manage a lot of buttons.
- The model never needs to know who shows it on screen.
- The QListView will autoscroll if necessary.
- Using a custom role allows us to easily retrieve the large image. If we added the large image in another column, it would show when using this model with a QTableView and when we want retrieve it from the selected index we would have to create a new index pointing to the right column. (Not really hard but require a little more code, and prone to error if we wrap the model in a ProxyModel)

### Lambda explanation

For the lambda in C++ the full syntax is:

```
[CAPTURES]\(PARAMETERS\)->RESULT {FUNCTION}.
```

- Between brackets we capture variables to be able to use them inside the FUNCTION without having to pass them as parameters.
- The PARAMETERS between parenthesis have the same signification as any other function, if omitted the lambda takes no parameters.
- RESULT is the return type of the FUNCTION and can be omitted.
- FUNCTION the body to execute

In this example I decided to ignore the parameters given by the signal so I omitted the parenthesis. I use the captured controls to retrieve the user selection and update the picture shown.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so. As it is, any future readers may not understand why you took this path and why this is organized the way it is.

Comment: @Avery I edited my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Very nice.. But I'm having trouble in a couple of places. First with setFlow(): It does exactly the opposite of what one would expect. The left pane appears as a row with QListView::TopToBottom and as a column with QListView::LeftToRight. That makes no sense. Also, I think that the connection says: when the member function (signal) "QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged" is triggered, call the lambda. But the signal emits "const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected" while the lambda receives "imageList, imagePresenter". How is that working?

Comment: You've got a strange behaviour with the setFlow() I tested it with qt5.3.1 and Mingw4.8.2 toolchain both in debug and release mode successfully.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain the lambda expression.